# Photoshop Script for Smart Objects out of fixed folder

Tags: batch-processing, photoshop-script

sorry for my not so good English, I hope you guys will understand what my problem is.. I don´t know really much about coding.

I have got the following code which allows to choose files that have to be changed in a smartobject in a psd document. I would like to have the code choose from a fixed folder like
../Desktop/Alldesigns
without asking which files I want to proceed.

I hope someone can help me...

```
#target photoshop
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var theName= myDocument.name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
var thePath = myDocument.path;
var theLayer = myDocument.activeLayer;
// jpg options;
var jpgopts = new JPEGSaveOptions();
jpgopts.embedProfile = true;
jpgopts.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
jpgopts.matte = MatteType.NONE;
jpgopts.quality = 9;
// check if layer is smart object;
if (theLayer.kind != "LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT") {alert ("selected layer is not a smart object")}
else {
// select files;
if ($.os.search(/windows/i) != -1) {var theFiles = File.openDialog ("please select files", "*.psd;*.tif;*.jpg", true)}
else {var theFiles = File.openDialog ("please select files", getFiles, true)};
if (theFiles) {
// work through the array;
          for (var m = 0; m < theFiles.length; m++) {
// replace smart object;
                    theLayer = replaceContents (theFiles[m], theLayer);
                    var theNewName = theFiles[m].name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
//save jpg;
                    myDocument.saveAs((new File(thePath+"/"+theNewName+"-"+theName+".jpg")),jpgopts,true);
                    }
          }
}
};
////// get psds, tifs and jpgs from files //////
function getFiles (theFile) {
     if (theFile.name.match(/\.(psd|tif)$/i) != null || theFile.constructor.name == "Folder") {
          return true
          };
     };
////// replace contents //////
function replaceContents (newFile, theSO) {
app.activeDocument.activeLayer = theSO;
// =======================================================
var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID( "placedLayerReplaceContents" );
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    desc3.putPath( idnull, new File( newFile ) );
    var idPgNm = charIDToTypeID( "PgNm" );
    desc3.putInteger( idPgNm, 1 );
executeAction( idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO );
return app.activeDocument.activeLayer
};
```

Best wishes from Germany
olee

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your code is used to batch replace a Smart Object in a PSD document, with all images from an input folder?

This modified code should work, to use a specific hardcoded folderpath, instead of requiring you to manually select it each time:

```
#target photoshop
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
    var theName= myDocument.name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
    var thePath = myDocument.path;
    var theLayer = myDocument.activeLayer;
    // jpg options;
    var jpgopts = new JPEGSaveOptions();
    jpgopts.embedProfile = true;
    jpgopts.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
    jpgopts.matte = MatteType.NONE;
    jpgopts.quality = 9;
    // check if layer is smart object;
    if (theLayer.kind != "LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT") {alert ("selected layer is not a smart object")}
    else {
        // get all files in the specified folder;
        var theFolder = new Folder('~/Desktop/Alldesigns');
        var theFiles = theFolder.getFiles(function(file) {
            return (file instanceof File && file.name.match(/\.(psd|tif|jpg)$/i));
        });
        if (theFiles.length > 0) {
            // work through the array;
            for (var m = 0; m < theFiles.length; m++) {
                // replace smart object;
                theLayer = replaceContents (theFiles[m], theLayer);
                var theNewName = theFiles[m].name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
                // save jpg;
                myDocument.saveAs((new File(thePath + "/" + theNewName + "-" + theName + ".jpg")), jpgopts, true);
            }
        } else {
            alert("There are no suitable files in the folder");
        }
    }
}

////// replace contents //////
function replaceContents (newFile, theSO) {
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer = theSO;
    var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID( "placedLayerReplaceContents" );
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    desc3.putPath( idnull, new File( newFile ) );
    var idPgNm = charIDToTypeID( "PgNm" );
    desc3.putInteger( idPgNm, 1 );
    executeAction( idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO );
    return app.activeDocument.activeLayer;
}
```

Note that if you want to have the images saved to a specific output folder, you'll need to make another modification to include that part.

Additionally, if you want to use several PSD documents (let's say you have 6 PSD documents you use, maybe you're creating mockup images for a website or something), you'll have to update the script to run this sequence for each one. To do that, you'll need to modify the filepaths accordingly -- and it's probably simplest to just wrap this in a function, then pass the different filepaths into the function as a parameter. That will allow you to automate this, from start to finish, to run batch replacement operations on several PSD documents -- not just one.

Last thing I'd point out, if you're not experienced with writing Photoshop scripts and want a simpler solution, there is a Photoshop plugin you can use that allows you to do this exact same thing called [Batch Replace Smart Objects](https://exchange.adobe.com/apps/cc/8e3097ba/batch-replace-smart-objects). It does what this script does, but you can also save operations that have multiple steps, perhaps if you want to run batch replacement operations on several different PSD documents in sequence. Honestly if you just need this simple process automated and don't know how to write/modify Photoshop scripts, that might be your better bet. Does the same thing but is way easier than trying to make custom modifications to .jsx scripts.