# Issues on Script that Replaces Smart object iterating through local subfolders for PNGs Batch Mockup

Tags: javascript, automation, photoshop, photoshop-script

Hello I'm Gianni a 18 years old student from Italy.

I will be greatful to whoever even who just bothers to read the entire message as I'm completely helpless and ingnorant on the topic ahaha.

I'm trying to use a working script on Photosop that will enable me to automate the replacement of smart object on a photoshop file with pngs found in a local directory and save each file as a jpg.

Here's in detail the steps I'd want to achieve:

Given the active layer smart object called "smart" in the psd file and given the fold_A = "C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\PROVA - Copia - Copia (5) - Copia - Copia - Copia - Copia - Copia", i need the code to walk through every subfolders' subfolders and for every png file that meets this criteria:

- it is a png file AND it is contained by a folder called "white".

The code must then take this png and replace it in the smart object.

After it does this, the code must export the file with all the layers as a jpg with 100% quality and the name being "[name of parent folder ( in this example "white")] + "SCAMBIABRO" + [name of png]", it must save this jpg into a path that needs to be adjusted for every export and will be the follwing:

same path as the png was taken in but change fold_A with fold_B = "C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Hoodie" . so for EXAMPLE:

if the png was taken from "C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\PROVA - Copia - Copia (5) - Copia - Copia - Copia - Copia - Copia\0002 heetsina\black"

then the jpg must be saved into "C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Hoodie\0002 heetsina\black".

Once done this the code must do the same procedure for every png that meets criteria, replacing the old smart object of the old png removing the old png and replacing it with the new png and do the same thing until it has done every png that meets criteria. Every time it saves the png into the new path the code must print it and once finished all the code, a print "FINITO" must be made.

I don't really have coding knowledge for Javascript and Photoshop code, however I've tried running this code:

``    #target photoshop

```
function processFolder(folder, fold_A, fold_B) {
var files = folder.getFiles();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
var file = files[i];
if (file instanceof Folder) {
if (file.name.toLowerCase() === "white") {
processFolder(file, fold_A, fold_B);
} else {
processFolder(file, fold_A, fold_B);
}
} else if (file.name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png") && folder.name.toLowerCase() === "white") {
replaceAndSave(file, fold_A, fold_B);
}
}
}

function replaceAndSave(pngFile, fold_A, fold_B) {
var smartObjectLayer = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("smart");
smartObjectLayer = replaceContents(pngFile, smartObjectLayer);

var jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
jpgSaveOptions.quality = 12;

var newFilePath = pngFile.path.replace(fold_A, fold_B);
var newFileName = "whiteSCAMBIABRO" + pngFile.name.replace(".png", ".jpg");
var newFile = new File(newFilePath + "/" + newFileName);

app.activeDocument.saveAs(newFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
$.writeln("Saved: " + newFile);
}

function replaceContents(newFile, theSO) {
app.activeDocument.activeLayer = theSO;
var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerReplaceContents");
var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
desc3.putPath(idnull, new File(newFile));
var idPgNm = charIDToTypeID("PgNm");
desc3.putInteger(idPgNm, 1);
executeAction(idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO);
return app.activeDocument.activeLayer;
}

 var fold_A = "C:\\Users\\Utente\\Desktop\\PROVA - Copia - Copia (5) - Copia - Copia - Copia - Copia - Copia";
var fold_B = "C:\\Users\\Utente\\Desktop\\Hoodie";

var startFolder = new Folder(fold_A);
processFolder(startFolder, fold_A, fold_B);

$.writeln("FINITO");``
```

that I sort of came up with using this https://github.com/MarshySwamp/JJMack-Archive/blob/main and https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Batch-Mockup-Smart-Object-Replacement-photoshop-script and [Photoshop Script for Smart Objects out of fixed folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315207/photoshop-script-for-smart-objects-out-of-fixed-folder/..). and https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/batch-replace-smart-objects-with-exis...

However it doesn't work and I have no Idea how to fix it.

Comment: With folder names like "C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\PROVA - Copia - Copia (5) - Copia - Copia - Copia - Copia - Copia\0002 heetsina\black" you need all the help you can get. However, SO isn't a script writing service. Grabbing some random script from the interwebs and then expecting it to do exactly what you want and not understanding what is does doesn't benefit anyone.

Comment: Ghoul I’m really sorry for you, you must be so good! Hope life will get better for you and you will have all the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explain your folder structure clearly - you don't mention where the source .psd file is located or anything.

Putting four scripts together and hoping they'll just work isn't really going to work. Go through them one at a time, function at a time and see if if works and what you need to do to change it.

So... the first thing that will fail is `.endsWith" in the processFolder function won't work in PhotoshopScripting as it's too new (Or is for me at least) . PS script uses ECMA script rather than up to date JavaScript. But we can replace it with a regular expression

```
else if (file.name.match(/\.(png)$/i) && folder.name.toLowerCase() === "white")
```

next if your source file is open, and your you currently layer is the SmartObject layer named "smart" you just need to call the action manager code that will process the layer and swap it out for the PNG that we just found.

```
function replaceContents(newFile) 
{
  var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerReplaceContents");
  var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
  desc3.putPath(idnull, new File(newFile));
  var idPgNm = charIDToTypeID("PgNm");
  desc3.putInteger(idPgNm, 1);
  executeAction(idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO);
}
```

So that now works. All you have to so is save it as a jpg. And the problem here was swapping the whole pathname (with slashes) rather than just "Folder A" for "Folder B" - We assume it exists - there's no check for that in the code!

So put the whole thing together:

```
// Switch off any annoying dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // OFF 

var fold_A = "D:\\temp\\process_images\\folder_A";
var fold_B = "D:\\temp\\process_images\\folder_B";

var startFolder = new Folder(fold_A);

processFolder(startFolder, fold_A, fold_B);


alert("FINITO");

function AndSave(pngFile, fold_A, fold_B)
{
  var smartObjectLayer = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("smart");
  smartObjectLayer = replaceContents(pngFile, smartObjectLayer);

  var jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  jpgSaveOptions.quality = 12;

  var newFilePath = pngFile.path.replace("folder_A", "folder_B");
  var newFileName = "whiteSCAMBIABRO" + pngFile.name.replace(".png", ".jpg");
  var newFile = new File(newFilePath + "/" + newFileName);

  app.activeDocument.saveAs(newFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
  alert("Saved: " + newFile);
}


function replaceContents(newFile) 
{
  var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerReplaceContents");
  var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
  desc3.putPath(idnull, new File(newFile));
  var idPgNm = charIDToTypeID("PgNm");
  desc3.putInteger(idPgNm, 1);
  executeAction(idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO);
}


function processFolder(folder, fold_A, fold_B)
{
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
  {
  var file = files[i];
  if (file instanceof Folder) {
  if (file.name.toLowerCase() === "white") 
  {
  processFolder(file, fold_A, fold_B);
  } else {
  processFolder(file, fold_A, fold_B);
  }
  } else if (file.name.match(/\.(png)$/i) && folder.name.toLowerCase() === "white") 
  {
    replaceContents(file);
    AndSave(file, fold_A, fold_B);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ghoul,

Thank you for the hassle and the time you've put in.

I promise I will get better at my folder naming ability!

Comment: Hi Ghoul,

If i wanted a code that does the exact thing that the "Generate Mockups" does in photopea.com (File-->Automate-->"Generate Mockups" deselect the stretch option, so it just fits the png to the smart object canvas proportionally).

So a code that takes the current active smart object layer and in inserts the pngs found from fold_A inside of it and export the full file as jpg full quality in fold_B, and then replaced each png one at a time and print "FINISH" when finished all.

But as PS script, how should it be?

Again, I'm incredibly thankful for what you've already done.